# Change text color on Navbar

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am unable to change one element of my Navbar to white (to match the others). I've tried the other questions on StackOverflow with CSS/HTML but it simply does not change!

Here is my HTML code:

Thanks,

Have tried CSS override on the color, but does not have any action.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #d35400;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">P s y c h l y t X | Scala: Client View</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Return to Scala application</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/scale">Edit my client's outcomes</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-text" >Welcome, <%= @user['info']['name'] %></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Which element? What have you tried?

Comment: Apologies, the element :

Comment: <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-text" >Welcome, <%= @user['info']['name'] %></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

Comment: it's black, the rest of the Nav-Bar is white text. I've tried overriding with CSS and HTML tags to no avail. Very strange that all text is white except this element without explicitly specifying it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Bootstrap:
change `navbar-dark` to `navbar-white` or `navbar-light` and add `text-dark`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light text-dark" style="background-color: #d35400;">
```

Comment: thanks Hitnux! I changed the it to<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark text-light" style="background-color: #d35400;"> and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {color: #FFFFFF;}
a:-webkit-any-link {color: #FFFFFF;}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #d35400;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">P s y c h l y t X | Scala: Client View</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Return to Scala application</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/scale">Edit my client's outcomes</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-text" >Welcome, <%= @user['info']['name'] %></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update, I tried this and the CSS has no effect on the text to the right, it's still black. Not sure what is overriding the color.

Comment: not to be that guy, but when you are checking are you pulling from cache? ie hit control f5 when refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Any of these classes aplied to the nav have the background-color property? If yes, try to put a !important after the color.

Answer (score 0):

If you've ever generated a scaffold the scaffold will come with its default css styling which can tamper with your css, so check your asset/stylesheet/scaffold.css and remove the css code there, see if it helps.